# Adding a reactive object to an array of my Vue component

Tags: arrays, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to get my Vue component to handle a list of objects with variable length with a date and boolean attribute.

The list is a list of vacation days for employees. I want to add vacation days and marks them as repeating every year.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-row v-for="vacation in employee.vacations" :key="vacation.id">
      <b-col>
        <b-input type="date" v-model="vacation.date"></b-input>
      </b-col>
      <b-col>
        <b-form-checkbox :v-model="vacation.yearlyRepetition">
          Jährlich wiederholend
        </b-form-checkbox>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>

    <b-button @click="addVacation">
      <b-icon-plus />
    </b-button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      employee: this.value,
    };
  },
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {
        return {
          vacations: [
            {
              id: "vac-1",
              date: "2022-12-23",
              yearlyRepetition: true,
            },
          ],
        };
      },
    },
  },
  methods: {
    addVacation() {
      this.employee.vacations.push({
        id: "vac-2",
        date: "2022-12-24",
        yearlyRepetition: false,
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

My problem is that for some reason **when the second checkbox is clicked, the value for the first checkbox changes**.

[GIF of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPPgA.gif)

This is probably some faulty combination of connections between

- props
- reactive objects
- List rendering

What can I do to fix this?

---

I've tried using `this.$set`, but I don't quite get it and nothing seemed to work.
When logging the data of the component, **all values seem to be set correctly**, but when I logged only the vacations, I realized that the originally (first) vacation day in the array is an Observer and the second one is a regular object. I don't understand the difference...

Comment: You aren't supposed to mutate a prop. Emit a change to parent component and change it there. That's the concept behind two-way binding

Comment: @EstusFlask This component is supposed to create changes using the v-model "attribute". I've tried creating a copy of the prop `value` and emitting a change using `this.$emit("input", updatedValue)`, but still no luck.

Comment: This isn't shown. v-model is not an attribute but a convention. If you wanted to use v-model then you had to use the respective event name (depends on Vue version which isn't listed). It's not practical to do deep changes with it because this would require to deep clone value object. Instead use custom event like add-vacation and push it in a parent.

Answer (score 1):

So, apparently `b-form-checkbox` from bootstrap-vue uses the id of the component to identify, which checkbox was clicked, instead of passing the value through and changing it.

So if the id of two checkboxes is equal, it changes the value of the first one by default. That's why my component did not work.

Setting the id of the checkbox component to something like `:id="'checkbox-' + vacation.id"` fixes the issue.